# .loc[] = value returns SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

**Problem**

I get the following error message with my code. Supposedly, the issue is that I am slicing the dataframe first with .loc and then attempting to assign values to that slice. From my understanding, Pandas isn't 100% sure if I want to assign values to just the slice, or have it propagate all the way back up to the original df. I'm not sure how to fix this.

**Error Message**

```
C:\blp\BQuant\environments\bqnt-1.25.2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:140: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

```
self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

**Full Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import time

csv1 = pd.read_csv('stock_price.csv', delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv1)

df['delta'] = df.PX_LAST.pct_change()
df.loc[df.index[0], 'avg_gain'] = 0

for x in range(1,len(df.index)):
    if df["delta"].iloc[x] > 0:
        df["avg_gain"].iloc[x] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1] * 13) + df["delta"].iloc[x]) / 14
    else:
        df["avg_gain"].iloc[x] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1] * 13) + 0) / 14   

df
```

**Input**

```
Dates,PX_LAST
03/09/2018,157.512
04/09/2018,155.393
05/09/2018,154.069
06/09/2018,155.109
07/09/2018,156.301
10/09/2018,156.717
11/09/2018,157.19
12/09/2018,157.549
13/09/2018,159.157
14/09/2018,158.363
17/09/2018,158.968
```

**Output**

```
Dates,PX_LAST,delta,avg_gain
03/09/2018,157.512,NaN,0
04/09/2018,155.393,-0.013453,0
05/09/2018,154.069,-0.00852,0
06/09/2018,155.109,0.00675,0.000482
07/09/2018,156.301,0.007685,0.000997
10/09/2018,156.717,0.002662,0.001116
11/09/2018,157.19,0.003018,0.001251
12/09/2018,157.549,0.002284,0.001325
13/09/2018,159.157,0.010206,0.00196
14/09/2018,158.363,-0.004989,0.00182
17/09/2018,158.968,0.00382,0.001963
```

**Line of Code that is the Issue**

```
for x in range(1,len(df.index)):
    if df["delta"].iloc[x] > 0:
        df["avg_gain"].iloc[x] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1] * 13) + df["delta"].iloc[x]) / 14
    else:
        df["avg_gain"].iloc[x] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1] * 13) + 0) / 14
```

**Solution**

I tried to use `.copy()` but I still get the same error message

```
for x in range(1,len(df.index)):
    if df["delta"].iloc[x] > 0:
        df["avg_gain"].iloc[x] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1].copy() * 13) + df["delta"].iloc[x].copy()) / 14
    else:
        df["avg_gain"].iloc[x] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1].copy() * 13) + 0) / 14
```

Thanks

Comment: The df is create by the subset of other df , when you slice it , adding .copy()

Comment: I tried adding .copy but I had no joy

Comment: Because you assign `df['avg_gain'].iloc[x]`, see this part [Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html].

Comment: I went through but I cant find a solution for this particular case

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do here but I feel like this could benefit from using [df.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and also [df.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

Comment: unfortunately, that method just gives NaN values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue code can be replaced with

```
for x in range(1,len(df.index)):
    if df["delta"].iloc[x] > 0:
        df.iloc[x, -1] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1] * 13) + df["delta"].iloc[x]) / 14
    else:
        df.iloc[x,-1] = ((df["avg_gain"].iloc[x - 1].copy() * 13) + 0) / 14
```

this because you added `avg_gain` last, so you can use `iloc[:,-1]` to access that column.

---

Update using `ewm`:

```
arg = df["delta"].clip(lower=0)
arg.iloc[0] = 0

df['avg_gain'] = arg.ewm(alpha=1/14, adjust=False).mean()
```

Output:

```
0     0.000000
1     0.000000
2     0.000000
3     0.000482
4     0.000997
5     0.001116
6     0.001251
7     0.001325
8     0.001960
9     0.001820
10    0.001962
Name: delta, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the output is just NaN when i use this code

Comment: @pythonlearner13 see my edit. This is a quick dirty fix. There should be a better vectorized way.

Comment: Any chance you would be able to help me on this as well?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870648/how-to-create-a-column-using-a-function-based-of-previous-values-in-the-column-i/57870840?noredirect=1#comment102167091_57870840

Comment: isn't it the same problem? change `df["var"].iloc[x]` on the left of `=` to `df.iloc[x,-1]`?

Comment: Slightly different. I am trying to get rid of the loop because it is slow and df.iloc[x, -1] would still mean i need a loop

Comment: That is so helpful. I have been trying for a long time to figure that out. Thanks a lot.